# Calmar VIM Font

Tags: fonts

Probably isn't the best place for this, but what font is this in this image? I simply cannot find out what it is. Nothing comes close to it except a variant of Proggy, but even that's way off.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but specific font identification questions are off topic. See [Let’s Play The Guessing Game « Blog – Stack Exchange](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's highly likely that it is 9x15 (only checked the normal font, the bold one looks way off but i guess it might also be 9x15).

More information here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_(typeface)

See examples here: http://mirtchovski.com/p9/fonts/